# AngularJS - change href Attribute based on whether user logged in?

Tags: angularjs

I have a icon which shown as user

```html
<a href="#/login" class="button  button-icon ion-android-
    person">User</a>
```

What I want is that if a user is already logged in, when click the button, redirect the page to the user profile page. If the user is not logged in, then redirect to login page.

I store the user info in sessionStorage, so I can easily check whether the user is logged in:

```
factory('$loginCheck', function() {
    return function() {
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('email')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
})
```

I know I could use directive to implement it, but I dont know exactly how to do so. What is the best practice to implement it? Any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref):

```
<a ng-href="{{ ctrl.getLink() }}" class="button button-icon ion-android-person">User</a>
```

Suppose that `ctrl` is a controller within the scope of your anchor element. You could define the `getLink` function like so:

```
function someController($loginCheck) {
    this.getLink= function() {
        return $loginCheck() ? '/user/profile' : '/login';
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks. But it only works for the first time. if the user logout later. the link would not change accordingly. I think I should use a event handler, and if a logout event being triggered, then change the button's url.

Comment: Since this syntax does not use [one-time biding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding), the problem probably lies within your `$loginCheck` factory. Maybe `sessionStorage` is not being cleared?

Comment: I see, but I still need a listener in the controller, so if the sessionStory is being cleared, then fire a event so the listener in controller could update the link accordingly. is that correct?

Comment: @GavinLuo I see that you accepted my answer, did you manage to solve your problem or your question still stands? Do you need more help?